# Limit of the inverse of the difference of two matrices in quadratic form

Tags: matrices, limits, inverse, quadratic-forms

Let $A=(a_{ij}(x))$ and $B=(b_{ij}(x))$ be invertible symmetric positive definite ${n\times n}$ matrices, $a_{ij}(x)\geq 0,\,b_{ij}(x)\geq0\,\forall i,j$,  also let $y$ be a $n$-vector.

Note that $Q=y^T(A-
B)^{-1}y$ is a scalar.

As $x\to \infty$, $a_{ij}(x)\to 0$, $b_{ij}(x)\to 0$. Can we prove that $|Q|\to \infty$? My suspect is due to $(A-B)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A-B)}\mbox{Adj}(A-B)$, so the determinant will tend to $zero$.

Comment: Why should the determinant tend to zero? It seems to me that the pair $A(x) = 2I$ and $B(x) = I$ (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix) satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Well, the $\lim det(A-B)=det(\lim (A-B))$.

Comment: Why do you suspect that $\lim(A-B) = 0$? Also, doesn't the example that I gave disprove your suspicion?

Comment: We are taking limits, we trying to figure out what happens to the elements of the inverse of a matrix which elements are approach zero. The identify above was just a try, I am trying to find another expression for the inverse of the difference of two matrices.

Comment: but nothing from the statement of your question indicates that the elements of the difference $A-B$ approach $0$.

Comment: I should have said that for some invertible matrix X  $\lim_{n\to \infty} X(n)^{-1}=(\lim_{n\to \infty}X(n))^{-1}$, so the elements of the difference tend to zero.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say with your most recent comment. It is true that $\lim_{n\to \infty} X(n)^{-1}=(\lim_{n\to \infty}X(n))^{-1}$, but why would that mean that the elemtns of the difference tend to zero?

Comment: take the element-wise difference $\lim_{x\to\infty} (a_{ij}(x)-b_{ij}(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty} a_{ij}(x)-\lim_{x\to\infty} b_{ij}(x))\rightarrow 0-0$, $0-0$ is not an indetermination, right?

Comment: You never claimed that $\lim_{x \to \infty} a_{ij}(x) = 0$ (or that $\lim_{x \to \infty}b_{ij}(x) = 0$) for all $i,j$

Comment: I did, look at the original post. Sorry it was a typo there... Please, sorry...

Comment: What you wrote is "As $x\to \infty$, $a_{ij}(x)\to 0\Leftrightarrow\,\,b_{ij}(x)\to 0$". This does not mean "for all $i,j$, $a_{ij}(x) \to 0$ and $b_{ij}(x) \to 0$". The current version is clear.

Comment: I very sorry, that left-right arrow was wrong, it's a comma instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that even if $A - B \to 0$, we might not have $|Q| \to \infty$. For example, consider
$$
A(x) = \frac 1x \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}, \quad B(x) = \frac 1x\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad y = \pmatrix{1\\1}.
$$
We have $Q = 0$ for all $x$, so that $\lim_{x \to \infty} |Q| = 0$.

---

Suppose that $M(x) = A(x)-B(x)$ is positive definite (for all $x$), $M(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and $y$ is non-zero. By the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, we have 
$$
Q(x) = y^TM^{-1}(x)y \geq \lambda_{\min}(M^{-1}(x)) \|y\|^2 = [\lambda_{\max}(M(x))]^{-1}\|y\|^2 \geq \|M(x)\|^{-1}\|y\|^2.
$$
Here, $\|M(x)\|$ could refer to any submultiplicative matrix norm (for instance, we can take the Frobenius norm $\|M\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j}m_{ij}^2}$). Since $M(x) \to 0$, we have $\|M(x)\| \to 0$. Since $\|y\| \neq 0$, it follows that $\|y\|^2/\|M(x)\| \to \infty$, so that we indeed have $Q(x) \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks... I am thinking of what conditions we could make on A, B and y, to have the result. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ludwig I can't be sure what kinds of conditions are "natural" for your context, but one idea is this: if we impose the constraint that $A - B$ must be positive definite for all $x$ (or negative definite for all $x$), then the condition holds whenever $y$ is non-zero.

Comment: this is the case, $A-B$ is positive define.

Comment: @Ludwig In the example that I construct, $A$ and $B$ satisfy the conditions of your question, but $A - B$ is not positive (or negative) definite

Comment: so, assuming $A-B>0$ for all $x$ and that $y$ is nonzero, how could we prove that $|Q|\to\infty$?

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: it seems all right. Many thanks.